# What to do with old users in /etc/shadow after formatting the home partition?

Tags: linux, admin

My `/home` partition was corrupted, so i had to backup the drive and format it. All of my other partitions including `/root` still work. I am willing to setup new users, but old users like `www-dev`, `avahi`, plus my personal old-user home folder still all exist in `/etc/shadow`. How can I delete them? Can i still use my `/root` partition?

**Update**: It turns out that the command `groups` shows only 1 group with the name `root`. I am confused and i don't know how to fix my system. The original groups made upon installing the system are all gone and creating a new user so i can work with does not add him to the groups with the right permissions like when the system was fix before.

I am still able to boot into my Linux OS and login with user root.

Comment: Your issue is confusing.  If `/home` is corrupted all other directories should be fine, restoring that directory should return the system to a known state. The `groups` command only lists the groups a user is in, it does not list all the groups in `/etc/group`.   Finally, you may want to take this question to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Most if not all Linux distributions start creating users and user-groups at UID/GID number 1000 if not by specification then by convention.  Most system-level users/groups (www-data, etc) will have much lower user numbers, in the low 100s or even less.

If all you did was wipe the contents of /home, and you have it backed up, simply restore the backup and check that file/directory ownership and permissions are correct, there is no need to mess with the contents of your `/etc/passwd` et al.

Since the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` files are all plain text, you can just open them with an editor and delete appropriate lines if you decide that you really need to.

Comment: Please just close the off-topic fodder.